# How to increase or decrease system volume from terminal?

Tags: command-line, volume-control

How to increase or decrease `overall system volume` from terminal like I was doing it in the GUI?

Comment: I fail to see how this is not a duplicate. The other answer might not have been optimal for Avinash's exact situation, but the questions are the same and, IMO, should be merged (although I won't do that right now).

Comment: @Seth this question is about the GUI volume, which is controlled exclusively by PulseAudio. The other question doesn't care what volume gets modified, as long as it produce the same result. I already explained it in my comment before. Related yes, duplicated, no.

Comment: @Braiam With respect, the other answers change the Pulseaudio sink volumes just as much as your answer does. Open up a Pulseaudio mixer and change the values in `alsamixer`. They're synced because ALSA is the sink in `pactl set-sink-volume`. The questions are duplicate because of these technicalities.